# How Can I Convert stored procedure from MS SQL to MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Please I have a problem when i try to write a stored  procedure on MySql,

My Procedure on SQL Server is :

//// SQL Server ///

```
create Proc [dbo].[P_TestSup] @para1 int, @para2 bit output as  
begin
        select @para2= count(IdCV) from CommandeVente,Client where
      CommandeVente.IdClnCV=Client.IdCln and IdCln=@para1   
End
```

I Try to Write it on MySQL but it's Incorrect

> Error: check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

////// MySql //////

```
CREATE PROCEDURE P_TestSup(IN para1 INT, OUT para2 bit) 
begin 
select count(commandevente.idcv) into para2 from commandevente,client 
   where commandevente.idclncv= client.idcln and client.idcln=para1;
End
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps your problem is the lack of `DELIMITER` statement.  And fix the `JOIN` syntax.  And the type of the output parameter.  Also, I would be careful about naming.

Something like this:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE P_TestSup(
    in_para1 INT,
    OUT out_para2 INT
) 
BEGIN 
    SELECT count(commandevente.idcv) into out_para2 
    FROM commandevente ce
         client c
         ON ce.idclncv = c.idcln ;
END;$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I'm Sorry my questions need some Edit
when i want to add a condition like ==>

and c.idcln= in_para1 ;

they said ; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON ce.idclncv = c.idcln and c.idcln= in_para1 ;
END' at line 3

Comment: Thanks For Helping , i use this code and it's working ===>
'
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `P_TestSup`(in in_para1 INT, OUT out_para2 INT)
BEGIN 
    SELECT count(commandevente.idcv) into out_para2 FROM commandevente ce ,client c where ce.idclncv = c.idcln and c.idcln= in_para1 ;
END$$
DELIMITER ;